# Link To Parent From Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How on earth do I link up to a parent resource? My `Companies` have many `Orders`.

In my orders view, I have listed the associated company with

```
@order.company.name
```

However, when I try and use link_to, it links only to the order:

```
<%= link_to @order.company.name, company_path %>
```

In my routes, I have this:

```
 resources :companies do 
    resources :orders do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

What's the fix and where can I read more about it?

Comment: depending on your route.rb. It is default? .company is your active record set? then you probably have to to use company.id  but give is more infos first.

Comment: Hi, made some edits above, thanks Jx

Comment: Sorted with:  <%= link_to @order.company.name, :controller => 'companies', :action => 'show', :id => @order.company.id %> Although not sure this is a bit ott. Jx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= link_to @order.company.name, company_path(@order.company) %>`

You have to pass something to `company_path` so that it knows which `Company` to get the path for. That is distinct form `companies_path` which returns the path for all the companies.

`/companies/12` 
vs 
`/companies`

Comment: So much nicer than my solution!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  I couldn't remember if that was the correct solution.

Comment: i Updated to take out the guess thing, and elaborate slightly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a model orders and a model companies. so companies has_many orders. If you setup this with the usual way your records are all have id as identifier. In this case company.id is the record id if you want to make a link back to the company page.